# If AC and BC are two equal chords, BA is produced to P and CP cuts the circle at T the how is CT:CB=CA:CP?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've been solving the following question,

> If AC and BC are two equal chords of a circle. BA is produced to any point P and CP, when joined cuts the circle at T then show that $\dfrac{CT}{CB}=\dfrac{CA}{CP}$?

I made a rough diagram and found that $\triangle PTB \sim \triangle PAC$. But this only gives $\dfrac{PT}{PA}=\dfrac{PB}{PC}$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\triangle{PTB}$ and $\triangle{PAC}$ are similar, we have
$$\frac{CA}{CP}=\frac{BT}{BP}\tag 1$$
By the way, we have $\angle{PBC}=\angle{BTC}$. (this is because $\angle{PBC}=\angle{BAC}=\angle{BTC}$.) Also, we have $\angle{PCB}=\angle{BCT}$. So, it follows that $\triangle{PBC}$ and $\triangle{BTC}$ are similar. So, we have
$$\frac{CB}{BP}=\frac{CT}{BT},$$
i.e.
$$\frac{BT}{BP}=\frac{CT}{CB}\tag 2$$
From $(1)(2)$, we have
$$\frac{CA}{CP}=\frac{CT}{CB}$$
as desired.

Comment: Why $\angle{CBP}=\angle{CTB}$? And why is e $∠CPB=∠ACT+∠CAP$?

Comment: @user103816: $\angle{CBP}=\angle{CTB}$ because $\angle{CBP}$ is the inscribed angle for the intercepted arc $AC$ and $\angle{CTB}$ is the inscribed angle for the intercepted arc $CB$. Here since $AC=CB$, we can have $\angle{CBP}=\angle{CTB}$. Also, $\angle{CPB}=180^\circ-\angle{CPA}=180^\circ-(180^\circ-\angle{ACT}-\angle{CAP})=\angle{ACT}+\angle{CAP}$. (consider $\triangle{ACP}$)

Comment: How is $∠CPB=180−∠CPA$?

Comment: @user103816: $P$ is on the line segment $AB$, so $\angle{CPA}+\angle{CPB}=180^\circ\Rightarrow \angle{CPB}=180^\circ-\angle{CPA}$.

Comment: No, according to the question P is outside the circle and lies on extended part of BA.

Comment: @user103816: Sorry, I've misunderstood the question. See the 'new' answer.